# mac sudo npm install -g protractor Error 404

Tags: angularjs, npm, protractor

When I run sudo npm install -g protractor, got the error, looks like there's no that folder/files. Is there anyone who knows how to solve the problem? Thanks very much :)

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 no such package available : @types/node
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/node' is not in the
npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!) npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'protractor'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

[npm install screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdHNI.png)

Comment: Even I updated node to v7.4.0 and npm to 4.1.1, same error, '@type/node' is not in the npm registry

Answer (score 1):

This is reproducible on node 6.9.2. I believe it is an error in npm for this version of node.

```
❯ nvm install 6.9.2                                                                                                                                 ⏎
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
WARNING: checksums are currently disabled for node.js v4.0 and later
Now using node v6.9.2 (npm v3.10.9)

❯ npm i - g @types/node
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/cnishina/-
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/cnishina/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/node" "/Users/cnishina/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/npm" "i" "-" "g" "@types/node"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /Users/cnishina/-
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cnishina/-'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cnishina/-'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/cnishina/npm-debug.log
```

After installing 6.9.3, the error goes away:

```
❯ nvm install 6.9.3
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.3/node-v6.9.3-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
WARNING: checksums are currently disabled for node.js v4.0 and later
npm i -g @tNow using node v6.9.3 (npm v3.10.10)


❯ npm i -g @types/node
/Users/cnishina/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.3/lib
└── @types/node@7.0.1
```

I also suggest installing the latest node 6. At the time of this post, it is node 6.9.4. I have checked installing `@types/node` also works for node 6.9.4.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried, updated npm but same error there :(

Comment: Are you using an npm caching layer? Like artifactory or nexus?

Answer (score 0):

Some people with the same problem found that decreasing the version to 4.0.4 helped. Buts seems a frequent error. Still not a cool solution, but seems to work for some.

Comment: So is there other ways to figure it out? Thanks :)